# POPUP on Button right click + WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I have a `ListBox` that is bound to a list of items. The `ListBoxItem` is bound to a datatemplate of type `Button`.

On the click of button, I do some action (another window is shown). So i have bound to the Command of the button.

Now my requirement is that i show a POPUP (with some buttons in popup) to the right click of the button.

How would i be able to do this in MVVM ?

- Girija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply catch `MouseUp` event from `ListBox.ItemTemplate` and set `Popup.IsOpen` there:

```
private void SomeTemplateElement_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
          puMyPopup.IsOpen = true;       
}
```

Popup is a view element, so I don`t think there`s a reason to open it through viewmodel commands.